# Calling a function from within a sequence construct in F#

Tags: f#, sequence

I am having problems calling a function from within a sequence construct.
Apparently, the function is being called so lazily that the overall code
does not produce the intended result. Here is the code:

```
 mylist
 |> fun myseq -> 
    seq { for b in mylist do yield { b with status = (getStatus b)}}
```

Here, mylist is a list of records. I intent to build a sequence out of it
with the field status updated from the function getStatus. It simply does
not work, the function does not appear to run for each iteration of the
for loop as expected.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequences are lazy. Your function will not run until the sequence is enumerated.

You need to turn the sequence into a concrete collection type like list or array (which will enumerate the sequence and force your function to run):

```
seq { for b in mylist do yield { b with status = getStatus b } }
|> Seq.toList
```

or, if you only care about side effects (which is not your case), use `Seq.iter`.

Comment: @ArmandoAcosta: Glad to hear that. You should accept the answer if it solved your problem.